# "future cannot be sent between threads safely" when pass Arc<Mutex> into tokio::spawn

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I implemented TCP client using tokio. However, my code not compile because I got an error:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:81:9
    |
81  |         tokio::spawn(async move {
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `impl Future<Output = ()>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Option<tokio::net::TcpStream>>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/main.rs:90:42
    |
82  |             match stream.lock().unwrap().as_mut() {
    |                   ---------------------- has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Option<tokio::net::TcpStream>>` which is not `Send`
...
90  |                     stream.write(&packet).await.unwrap();
    |                                          ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `stream.lock().unwrap()` maybe used later
...
94  |             };
    |              - `stream.lock().unwrap()` is later dropped here
help: consider moving this into a `let` binding to create a shorter lived borrow
   --> src/main.rs:82:19
    |
82  |             match stream.lock().unwrap().as_mut() {
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.19.2/src/task/spawn.rs:127:21
    |
127 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
```

This is my code where issue occurs:

```
async fn handle_write(&mut self) -> JoinHandle<()> {
    let stream = Arc::clone(&self.stream);
    let session = Arc::clone(&self.session);
    let queue = Arc::clone(&self.queue);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        match stream.lock().unwrap().as_mut() {
            Some(stream) => {
                let packet: Vec<u8> = queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front().unwrap();
                let packet = match session.lock().unwrap().header_crypt.as_mut() {
                    Some(header_crypt) => header_crypt.encrypt(&packet),
                    _ => packet,
                };

                stream.write(&packet).await.unwrap();
                stream.flush().await.unwrap();
            },
            _ => {},
        };
    })
}
```

and same issue here:

```
async fn handle_read(&mut self) -> JoinHandle<()> {
    let queue = Arc::clone(&self.queue);
    let stream = Arc::clone(&self.stream);
    let session = Arc::clone(&self.session);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        match stream.lock().unwrap().as_mut() {
            Some(stream) => {
                let mut buffer = [0u8; 4096];

                match stream.read(&mut buffer).await {
                    Ok(bytes_count) => {
                        let raw_data = match session.lock().unwrap().header_crypt.as_mut() {
                            Some(header_crypt) => header_crypt.decrypt(&buffer[..bytes_count]),
                            _ => buffer[..bytes_count].to_vec(),
                        };

                        queue.lock().unwrap().push_back(raw_data);
                    },
                    _ => {},
                };
            },
            _ => {},
        };
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=332aa171783998be9e8b2507d9ca2b98).

Could somebody explain, what am I doing wrong ?

P.S. just in case: I am using `std::sync::{Arc, Mutex}`;

Comment: You aren't sending the mutex, but the lock guard -- and this clearly can't work, `std::Mutex`'s invariant is that its lock owned by a single thread.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you mean I should use `use tokio::sync::{Mutex};` instead ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo for instance yes. The problem you have is that tokio can resume coroutines on different threads than it paused them, so you can't keep std locks across `await` when using `tokio::spawn`. Alternatively you can use [`spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_local.html) which runs entirely on the scheduler where it came from.

Comment: @Masklinn is it good practice to call tokio::spawn_local inside tokio::spawn ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo [no](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.LocalSet.html#use-inside-tokiospawn)

Comment: [Although there are workarounds, of sort](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/2095).

Comment: @Masklinn I need `handle_read`, `handle_write` and `handle_queue` to be processed independently in different threads. Could you advice what I can do to achieve this ?

Comment: Fixed: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=437174331c2644acdcc7f929b32c921d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, as decided in comments to my question, I used `tokio::sync::Mutex` instead of `std::sync::Mutex`. So, now code compiles correctly.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=437174331c2644acdcc7f929b32c921d).

Comment: This was very simple solution. `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Option<tokio::net::TcpStream>> which is not Send` was telling the same thing. If someone is not using the mutex inside the `Arc` then unsafe implementations of `Send` and `Sync` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was using `ThreadRng` with `thread_rng()` which is NOT thread safe. Just as a heads-up for anyone else banging their head against this error message. I refactored to using `let mut rng = ::rand::rngs::StdRng::from_seed(OsRng.gen());`